# How to understand the output key of tflite file

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-lite

I am learning and running the tensorflow Pi Camera [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi), but don't know how to understand the output key of tflite file? such as the key "quantization" of https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi/classify_picamera.py#L52 , any document ?

Answer (score 0):

You can look [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-accelerate-and-compress-neural-networks-with-quantization-edfbbabb6af7) about `quantization`

> The fundamental idea behind quantization is that if we convert the weights and inputs into integer types, we consume less memory and on certain hardware, the calculations are faster.

And I'm not sure what you are asking about the output file. But you can process your tflite file inside [this git repo](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) to understand what input your model needs and  what will be the output

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the description for post-training quantization https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#representation_for_quantized_tensors and quantization specification https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec.